# How to call Dialog box from Notification bar in android?

Tags: android, notifications

I would like to call an android dialog box from Notification bar in android instead of leading to a url.Here is my code which I am using to call a url from notification.Tell me how to do it for a dialog box.Thanks

```
notifyDetails.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
Context context = getApplicationContext();
CharSequence contentTitle = "Notification Details...";
CharSequence contentText = "Browse Android Official Site by clicking me";
Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://www.android.com"));

PendingIntent intent = 
                PendingIntent.getActivity(SimpleNotification.this, 0, 
                notifyIntent, android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

notifyDetails.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, intent);
mNotificationManager.notify(SIMPLE_NOTFICATION_ID, notifyDetails);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just make the pendingintent open up one of your activities and have your activity be complete transparent and just open a dialog.

**EDIT** adding flag to intent

```
Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(context,YourActivityClassHere.class);
notifyIntent.setFlag(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
//UNIQUE_ID if you expect more than one notification to appear
PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(SimpleNotification.this, UNIQUE_ID, 
            notifyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: Does this work when we exit the app & tend to get a c2dm notification.

Comment: yes when you click the notification it will fire up your activity so even if its closed it will fire up your activity turning on your application context. final note make sure to add Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK to the intent editing my answer above.